# Difference between 仏教絵画 and 仏画

Tags: word-choice, nuances, religion

仏教絵画 and 仏画 each have their own Wikipedia article, which is an almost sure sign that they are different concepts.

[仏教絵画](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%BB%8F%E6%95%99%E7%B5%B5%E7%94%BB):

> 仏教を題材とした絵画である。寺院の壁画、絹、紙、板に描いた絵画、版画等を含む。

[仏画](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%BB%8F%E7%94%BB):

> 広義には、仏教絵画全般を指し、仏伝、本生譚、浄土変相図（当麻曼陀羅など）、来迎図、二河白道図、六道絵などの仏教説話画、祖師絵伝、絵巻、祖師図、禅宗僧の肖像画でいう頂相、一般僧の肖像画なども含む。

I still don't clearly understand how they differ. Can you enlighten me?

For instance, when given a particular painting, on what criteria can I declare "*This painting is 仏画 but not 仏教絵画*", or the opposite?

Answer (score 3):

仏教絵画 is self-explanatory; any painting that's related to Buddhism.

---

As for 仏画, Wikipedia says:

> 仏画（ぶつが）とは、広義には、仏教絵画全般を指し、 (中略) 狭義には仏教、特に密教系宗派の礼拝・儀式で使用される絵画。

デジタル大辞泉 says:

> 仏教絵画。狭義には礼拝の対象とされる仏や菩薩【ぼさつ】などの画像をいう。

ブリタニカ国際大百科事典 says:

> 普通は礼拝の対象とされる仏教諸尊の絵像や曼荼羅図をさすが，広義には仏教的な主題をもった絵画全般をいう。

百科事典マイペディア says:

> 仏像彫刻に対し，礼拝の対象となる仏教尊像の画像と修法の本尊である曼荼羅【まんだら】図をさす。広義には仏教絵画の総称

大辞林 第三版 says:

> 仏の姿を描いた絵。また、仏教に題材をとった絵画。

日本大百科全書 says:

> 仏教絵画のことで、広義には仏教の宗教活動のために描かれた仏教を主題にした絵画の総称。狭義には仏教彫像（仏像）に対応する意味に用いられ、礼拝の対象となる仏教の尊像を表した画像をさす。

So 仏画 in the broader sense is a simple equivalent of 仏教絵画, but it sometimes specifically refers to a painting of (human-shaped) Buddha which is meant to be worshiped.

I think 仏画 is a relatively uncommon word, and 仏教絵画 or 仏教画 is usually used to objectively refer to Buddhist paintings in general in fine art and archaeological contexts. From what I understand, all 仏画 are also 仏教絵画 by definition, but not vice versa. I feel [portraits of monks](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%A0%82%E7%9B%B8) are safely called 仏教絵画, but calling them 仏画 sounds a bit profane to me. A [地獄絵図](https://search.yahoo.co.jp/image/search?ei=UTF-8&fr=sfp_as&aq=-1&oq=&ts=1248&p=%E5%9C%B0%E7%8D%84%E7%B5%B5%E5%9B%B3&meta=vc%3D) is safely a 仏教絵画, but I personally hesitate to call it a 仏画.